# Rails 4 - getting ActiveRecord::UnkknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: checker_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, railstutorial.org

Beginner Rails programmer here.
I'm getting the following errors when running my rspec tests:

```
1) User checking 
     Failure/Error: @user.check!(other_user)
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./app/models/user.rb:33:in `check!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User checking checked user checkers 
     Failure/Error: @user.check!(other_user)
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./app/models/user.rb:33:in `check!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User checking checked_users 
     Failure/Error: @user.check!(other_user)
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./app/models/user.rb:33:in `check!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User checking and unchecking 
     Failure/Error: @user.check!(other_user)
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./app/models/user.rb:33:in `check!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User checking and unchecking checked_users 
     Failure/Error: @user.check!(other_user)
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./app/models/user.rb:33:in `check!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Relationship 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Relationship when checked id is not present 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Relationship checker methods 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) Relationship checker methods 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  10) Relationship checker methods checked 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  11) Relationship checker methods checker 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  12) Relationship when checker id is not present 
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: checker_id
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/relationship_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

which all come down to 'unkknown attribute: checker_id'.

I've already tried

- running `rake db:reset` -> `rake db:migrate`-> `rake test:prepare`
- restarting the server
- checking the table in pgAdmin3; the table as well as the checker_id column do exist there
- compared all the files to the Railstutorial sample app on github

I'm following Michael Hartl's Tutorial while changing some parts of the sample app. My implementation here should be practically the same as in [chapter 11.1](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-the_relationship_model), except that I've changed all the follower, following, followed_id etc. to checker, checking, checked_id etc.

I've pasted the relevant files below:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "checker_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :checked_users, through: :relationships, source: :checked
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "checked_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :checkers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :checker

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token

    validates :name, presence: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email,   presence:   true,
                        format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

    def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  def checking?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(checked_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def check!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(checked_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def uncheck!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(checked_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Test User", email: "test@example.com", 
                        verified:true, about_text:"About Text", 
                        success_text:"Success Text", password: "foobar",
              password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:verified) }
  it { should respond_to(:about_text) }
  it { should respond_to(:success_text) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  it { should respond_to(:admin) }
  it { should respond_to(:relationships) }
  it { should respond_to(:checked_users) }
  it { should respond_to(:checking?) }
  it { should respond_to(:check!) }
  it { should respond_to(:reverse_relationships) }
  it { should respond_to(:checkers) }

  it { should be_valid }
  it { should_not be_admin }

  describe "with admin attribute set to 'true'" do
    before do
      @user.save!
      @user.toggle!(:admin)
    end

    it { should be_admin }
  end

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "whenn password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "example@example.com",
                        password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that is too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) {
        found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end

  describe "checking" do
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      @user.save
      @user.check!(other_user)
    end

    it { should be_checking(other_user) }
    its(:checked_users) { should include(other_user) }

    describe "checked user" do
      subject { other_user }
      its(:checkers) { should include(@user) }
    end

    describe "and unchecking" do
      before { @user.uncheck!(other_user) }

      it { should_not be_checking(other_user) }
      its(:checked_users) { should_not include(other_user) }
    end
  end
end
```

**relationship.rb**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :checker, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :checked, class_name: "User"
  validates :checker_id, presence: true
  validates :checked_id, presence: true
end
```

**relationship_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Relationship do

  let(:checker) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:checked) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:relationship) { checker.relationships.build(checked_id: checked.id) }

  subject { relationship }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "checker methods" do
    it { should respond_to(:checker) }
    it { should respond_to(:checked) }
    its(:checker) { should eq checker }
    its(:checked) { should eq checked }
  end

  describe "when checked id is not present" do
    before { relationship.checked_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when checker id is not present" do
    before { relationship.checker_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

**20140818183201_create_relationships.rb**

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :checker_id
      t.integer :checked_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :checker_id
    add_index :relationships, :checked_id
    add_index :relationships, [:checker_id, :checked_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

I'm super grateful for any idea that brings me forward on this! thanks!

**EDIT/UPDDATE:** I've checked the development database at each step when doing `rake db:reset` -> `rake db:migrate`-> `rake test:prepare`. After `rake db:migrate` the users table is filled with sample users, but `rake test:prepare` erases all those users, leaving the table empty. 
Maybe there's a connection here. Might `checker_id`be unavailable because `rake test:prepare` deletes it?

Comment: did you run the migration in test mode as well?
`bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Yes. It didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error you post, 
`unknown attribute: checker_id`

refers to an attribute, checker_id, that is not present in your code on line 33:

```
 relationships.create!(checked_id: other_user.id)
```

So either you're posting the wrong code, or you need to restart your testing server, or there's some other problem.  But basically, your test suite is not testing what you think it's testing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting all the files and changes i had made since the beginning of chapter 10, then copy-pasting all the changes from the tutorial. I don't know what exactly i had done wrong, but this solved the issue.